# getting text from select options and sending it to input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Want to hone in on my javascript. I want text from select-option dropdown sent to an input. ive found a way to do it.. but my question is- is there a shorter way (in vanilla javascript)?

```
<select id="gren" onChange="return func1(this)"><option>1</option><option>2</option>
<option>3</option><option>4</option></select>
<input style="text" id="testing">
```

with

```
<script>
function func1(select){
var rr = document.getElementById("gren");
var jest = rr.options[rr.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("testing").value = jest; }
</script>
```

i was thinking something along the lines of:

```
function func1(select){document.getElementById("testing").value = 
this.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;}
```

but it's not working.. why?

Comment: `innherHTML` = `innerHTML`. And what is not working? Errors in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select` variable instead of `this` keyword

```
function func1(select) {
    document.getElementById("testing").value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innherHTML;
    //OR
    document.getElementById("testing").value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="gren" onChange="return func1(this)"><option>1</option><option>2</option>
<option>3</option><option>4</option></select>
<input style="text" id="testing">
<script>
function func1(select){document.getElementById("testing").value = 
select.value;}
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<select id="gren" onChange="return func1(this)"><option>1</option><option>2</option>
<option>3</option><option>4</option></select>
<input style="text" id="testing">
<script>
function func1(select){document.getElementById("testing").value = 
select.innerHTML;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter isn't always better, code clarity and readability is what you want - as well as good structure. If you want to improve your JavaScript then start by never using inline attributes for event handling, such as `onchange`.

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/LYLFZ) and code below:

HTML:

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="myInput">
```

JavaScript:

```
var select = document.querySelector('.mySelect');
var input = document.querySelector('.myInput');
var updateInput = function () {
    input.value = this.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
};
select.onchange = updateInput;
```

Comment: @user3108832 Google around you'll find many reasons, the main being too tightly coupling HTML+JS, as well as the fact you're polluting the global scope with functions to make them accessible in the DOM. Plus this is 90's style coding, not 2014.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong `this` using and syntax error:

```
function func1(select){document.getElementById("testing").value = 
**this**.options[select.selectedIndex].inn**h**erHTML;}
```

`this` is window in your code.

Try this:

```
 function func1(select){document.getElementById("testing").value = 
**select**.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 function func1(select){
      document.getElementById("testing").value = select.text;
  }
```